# Max $2x+3y$ subject to $4x+y \leq 5, x\geq0, y\geq0$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

**Qno:**
(a)
obtain a solution $(x^{*}, y^{*})$  by graphical method.

(b) Formulate the Lagrangean.

(c) Obtain all the K-T necessary conditions

(d) Using values for $(x^{*}, y^{*})$, obtain the values for the Lagrange multipliers in the problem.

(e) obtain the dual problem.

**Solution:** (a) I have done it.

(b) I have done it.

(c) I have done it.

(d) I got stuck in here.

The K-T means Kuhn Tucker necessary conditions were

$$L_x=2+4 \times \lambda, x \geq 0, x \times L_x=0 \implies L_x=0 $$

$$L_y=3+ \lambda, y \geq 0, y \times L_y=0 \implies L_y=0$$

$$L_{\lambda}=-5+4x+y,  \lambda \geq 0, \lambda \times L_{\lambda}=0 \implies L_{\lambda}=0$$

From these, I have

$$2+4 \times \lambda = 0$$

$$3+\lambda=0$$

$$-5+4x+y=0$$

Case1: Assume $\lambda ≠0$

Case2: Assume $\lambda=0$

I don't know how to tackle these two cases in order to find the values of $x, y, \lambda$ to maximize the utility function. I have tried my best but unable to get the true answer.

Also help me to get dual problem or at least give me hint for that part. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ is linear non-constant, therefore it has no critical points. This is also justified by the system
\begin{cases}
f_x=2\ne 0\\
f_y=3\ne 0
\end{cases}
Similarly, the function $L(x,y,\lambda)=2x+3y+\lambda(4x+y-5)$ has no critical point (this follows from your result).

However, $f$ is continuous and the considered domain is compact, therefore $f(x,y)$ achieves maximal and minimal value on the domain. The candidates for "where" it happens are the intersection points of the lines $x=0,\; y=0,\; 4x+y-5=0.$
Find the three points, put their coordinates in $f(x,y).$ The greatest is the maximum, the lowest ist minimum of $f(x,y)$ on the domain.

Comment: Actually, I have tried my best since last two days but I am unable to find $x, y and \lambda$ from above three questions keep in view of assumptions for $\lambda$ and dual form .

Comment: I found $(x*, y*, \lambda)=(0, 5, 0)$ which maximize the utility function. I don't know if it is correct

Comment: The aim is to maximize $f(x,y),$ not $L(x,y,\lambda).$ Right, maximum is obtained  for $(x*,y*)=(0,5).$ For this function is the method of Lagrangian multipliers useless.

Comment: Thank you. Got it.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for accepting my answer. If you find it useful, please upvote.

Comment: I have uploaded another question latest one. Kindly help me out. It is about hessian determinant. I know it. But the function is given has different 4 variables so I don't know that trick for 4 variables